# Is there a way to transform horizontally formatted CSV output to vertical when converting XML to CSV in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have an XML that I convert to a CSV, that works fine and outputs rows into the CSV.  I'd like to format the csv vertically vs horizontally.

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content "C:\temp\test.xml")
$data = $xml.SelectNodes("//EmployeeImport/Employee") | Select-Object -Property *
$data | Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\employee.csv" -NoTypeInformation 
$csvFile = "c:\temp\employee.csv"
$folderPath = Split-Path -Parent $csvFile
$csv = Import-Csv -Path $csvFile -Delimiter "," 

foreach ($record in $csv) {
    $OutFileName = join-path -Path $folderPath -ChildPath $($record.FirstName + " " + $record.LastName  +  $record.HireDate.replace('/','_') + ".csv");
    $record | select-object * | export-csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $OutFileName -Delimiter ",";
}
```

Current Output

| Name | Social |
| --- | --- |
| Mickey | 123456 |

Desired Output

| Name | Mickey |
| --- | --- |
| Social | 123456 |

Comment: Use `Format-List`?

Comment: When I use that it exports out some random characters and no where near what I was expecting.

Comment: Ok I tried again using Format-List and it's still out-putting horizontally.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Hard to say without some example data. Consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when posting questions

Answer (score 0):

This [`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) is basically meant to two join object lists based on a related property (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026) but as it might also be used to do a side-by-side join (by omitting the related property define by the `-on` parameter). This can be useful to transpose tables as e.g. a `csv` file:

```
Install-Module -Name JoinModule -MinimumVersion 3.8.1
```

**Sample Csv**

```
$Csv = @'
"@","A","B","C"
"1","D","E","F"
"2","G","H","I"
"3","J","K","L"
'@
```

#### As Matrix

Considering a Csv file (or string) as a matrix were the header row has the same format as each following data row, you might just separate each field on the comma delimiter:

```
$Table = @()
# Get-Content .\My.csv |Foreach-Object { ...
$Csv -Split '\r?\n' |Foreach-Object { $Table = $Table |FullJoin $_.Split(',') }
$Transposed = $Table |Foreach-Object { $_ -Join ',' }
```

**Explanation**

- `$Csv -Split '\r?\n'` splits the multiline string in an array of lines which is the default behavior of the `Get-Content` cmdlet

  - *Note:* this approach doesn't take in account that the data might also contain a comma, e.g.:
    `"Name","Social"`
    `"Mickey","123,456"`
- `$Table = $Table |FullJoin $_.Split(',')` full joins each row as a column to the prior row and output a list of `PSObject` collections ( `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]]`) similar to the [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays#foreach) and [`where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays#where) methods

  - *Note:* there is a bug in the versions prior to `3.8.1` of the `Join-Object` cmdlet that doesn't correctly implement the start from an empty pipeline (`$Table = @()`)
- `$Table |Foreach-Object { $_ -Join ',' }` iterates through each row of `PSObject` collections and joins each item (using the [`-join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join) *operator*) as a single string.

#### As List of PowerShell objects

```
$Data = ConvertFrom-Csv $Csv # = $xml.SelectNodes("//EmployeeImport/Employee")
$Names = $Data[0].PSObject.Properties.Name
$Last = $Names.get_Count() - 1
$Table = @() |FullJoin $Names[1..$Last] -Name $Names[0]
$Data |Foreach-Object {
    $Values = $_.PSObject.Properties.Value
    $Last = $Values.get_Count() - 1
    $Table =  $Table |FullJoin $Values[1..$Last] -Name $Values[0]
}
```

**Explanation**
In this case the input is considered to contain a list of PowerShell objects. Where it is common that each row is a PowerShell object and each property in the object represents a column.

- This means that the header row  is actually contained by the first (and all other rows) in the `$Data[0].PSObject.Properties.Name`
- The same counts for rebuilding the output where the first item should be considered to be the property name of each object. This is done with the command: `... |FullJoin $Names[1..$Last] -Name $Names[0]`